# How can I separate paragraphs in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

How can I separate paragraphs in comments? Is such a feature provided for comments? Sometimes I need to write a piece of code in comments and that's when I really need to separate lines from each other, but it seems that I can't do it in comments.

Comment: You can't. (stupid 15 character limit)

Comment: John, thanks for this idea, but my point in talking about paragraphs was in the difficulty of writing scripts (code) in comments, a case when I really need to separate one line from another. In your examples here you still couldn't separate lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments were not really designed for this. If you need to add code, consider editing your initial answer (if applicable), or write your own answer. If it's just a short snippet, I'm sure most people will understand what you're trying to say (unless the code is in [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), in which case you're out of luck).

That way, the community can upvote/downvote your answer based on its value. If it's a comment, it can only be upvoted, which doesn't always say much.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Brilliant :)! Glad to know I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Paragraphs and code snippets are not supported in comments.

If you need to write a piece of code, or even more then one paragraph, in comments, **you're not using the system correctly**. Major changes to a question/answer should be done as edits to the original question/answer, not as comments. The commenting feature is for extended discussion of a question/answer.

Meta is an exception, and often extended discussions lead to multiple comments by a single OP.

Comment: s/your/you're/  (......)

Comment: Except that sometimes I find extended discussion of an answer takes a lot of characters.